# Render texture and normalized view rect in Unity

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, textures, render, render-to-texture

I'm using Unity 3D 3.5 pro.

I've got this scene with two cameras in it. One of them is looking at a plane that has a render texture on it. The other is recording the render texture. When the camera that's recording the render texture has a 1:1 normalized view and height rect, everything is fine. But when It's something different, some weird stuff happens -- the render texture's image becomes distorted. I've tried releasing and discarding the render texture's contents in an update function, but nothing changes! It's totally stopping the project I'm working on from being completed. I have pictures here to explain the situation in detail. The reason its a problem is because i need to be able to place non rectangular objects in front of the square and not have their scales appear to be distorted, due to the scale of the plane on which the render texture is being shown not being a square. What could I be doing wrong?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/prdDVR3.png]

[image: http://imgur.com/hzdmJyv]

I also placed a similar question on unity answers, but received no usable help there. Here was the thread:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/389094/rendertexture-normalized-view-rect.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to mess with the offset and tiling of the rendertexture. Silly rabbit!